# JSONProvider returns empty objects such as String

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, cxf

I use `JAXB` and `JSONProvider` class for generating response to client in my REST services. And I have found one interesting thing. 
I have the mapping:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fooRoot")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WSBar {
     private WSFooTO foos;
//...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WSFooTO {
    private WSDateTO one;
    private WSDateTO two;
    private WSDateTO three;
    private WSDateTO four;
//....
}
```

When I set to the response empty objects, I mean: just `new WSDateTO()` and `new WSFooTO ()` 
After the, I recive answer like this:

```
{"fooRoot":{
    "foos":{
        "one":"",
        "two":"",
        "three":"",
        "four":""
    }
}}
```

Why does it happen? I expect, that it should be: "one":null, "two":null

Answer (score 2):

According to a JAXB [tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_12_8-No-Value.html#No%20Value) the absence of a value can be expressed in three different ways:

- the element is omitted
- with an empty String using `@XmlElement(required = true)` annotation
- with the sepcial `xsi:nil` attribute using `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` annotation

Answering strictly your question: JAXB does not support translating empty objects to `null`.

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858598/jaxb-marshalling-with-null-fields question which also shows a way to translate empty objects.

Comment: Thank you! But I think, that it's wrong, when object converts to String. Android client' s JSON parser doesn't work. Because it expects Object, not String.  Could you please tel, what should I do in the situation?

Comment: I don not understand what do you want to do. You asked `Why does it happen?` I pointed out why it happens. This is how the JAXB works. What do you want to do now? Please clarify your question. BTW `String` is also an `Object` so your Android client (about which you should give some info if that is the problem) should work.

Comment: To clarify, @Andrew was asking about the Android use case.  Atticus, thanks for your response.  I don't intend for the objects to be empty and I have verified to the best of my ability that they are not empty.  However, they're showing up as empty when I'd expect them to be populated.